# For Data-Grid view in ASP.Net, How to display a message if a particular row's column value is null

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

i am calling a procedure to display data in data grid but in my data grid view some columns are having null value and it comes blank so i want to get a message saying "please enter information for particular row"

my data grid view header are

Id English-name Marathi-name Address

1       Xyz       (Blank)    test1

2       pqr       (Blank)    test2

3       abc   (marathi-name) test3

now in this above example for row 1 and 2 'Marathi-name' is 'null' while row 3 is having data.In this case i want to display msg for ID's 1 and 2 please update information by going on customer information page" if yes tell me how ?

for not having null values i have updated table design in database but data is too large to update through back-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is about handling RowDataBound event. then you can change cells contents without modifying the underlying database.

```
Protected Sub gv_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gv.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "" Then e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "(please enter information here)"
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to collect IDs you could use gridview's DataBound event instead

```
Protected Sub gv_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gv.DataBound
  Dim listOfIDs As String
  For jRow As Integer = 0 To gv.Rows.Count - 1
        If gv.Rows(jRow).Cells(1).Text = "" Then listOfIDs &= gv.Rows(jRow).Cells(0).Text & ", "
  Next jRow
  Label1.Text = "Please update Rows " & listOfIDs 
End Sub
```